# Translate PL/SQL define to TSQL

Tags: t-sql, plsql, sqlplus, sqlcmd

I am given a task to transition PL/SQL code to T-SQL.

Can anybody explain what `SET DEFINE ON` does in sqlplus and most impooirtantly how to translate it to T-SQL (I suppose using sqlcmd as a launcher?)

Comment: `SET DEFINE` is an SQL*Plus command setting the use and prefix for substitution variables. `&` is the default prefix and `SET DEFINE ON` resets it to this default and turns on the use of substitution variables. So this is not a PL/SQL thing. As far as I know there's no such thing as substitution variables for `sqlcmd`, i.e. there's no equivalent. But I might be wring there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SET DEFINE` is an SQL*Plus command setting the use and prefix for substitution variables. `&` is the default prefix and `SET DEFINE ON` resets it to this default and turns on the use of substitution variables.

So this is not a PL/SQL thing but an SQL*Plus thing.

As far as I know there's no such thing as substitution variables for `sqlcmd`, i.e. there's no equivalent for `sqlcmd` let alone T-SQL. But I might be wrong there.

Answer (score -1):

'&' appears to be a token of the metalanguage used by SQL*Plus (the client, that is) to activate its "variable substitution" feature.  So string literals containing '&' ("Marks & Spencer") tokens may not behave entirely as expected.  SET DEFINE apparently serves to control that activation.